# How to change one edit form from two buttons?

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

I have 2 WPF forms. 
In form1, I have 2 buttons(add,edit) and in form2, 3 fields. When I click on 1 of 2 buttons open form2. How to make, when I click on button **Add** in second form all fields are **'IsEnabled="True"'**, but when I click **Edit** button, 1 field to be **IsEnabled="False"** in second form!?
10x

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Try to pass values after you clicked a button, test the passed values on formload of the second form and enable/disable specific fields dfepending on your passed values.

Comment: i try :

     form2 Dr = sender as form2;
                Dr.tboxName.IsEnabled = true;
but give me error for not instance

Comment: Why have you ticked that ridiculous answer as the correct answer? Is that another of your accounts?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a public `bool` property to bind to:

```
private bool canEdit = false;

public bool CanEdit
{
    get { return canEdit; }
    set { canEdit = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("CanEdit"); }
}
```

Then bind it to the `IsEnabled` properties of the `TextBox` controls:

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding CanEdit, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
AncestorType={x:Type YourXmlNamespace:YourParentForm}}}" />
```

Then just set it to `true` in either your `Click` handler, or your `Command` handler to make the `TextBox` controls enabled:

```
CanEdit = true; // Makes TextBox.IsEnabled = true
```

Notes:

You *may* prefer to add another `bool` property for your one control that should be enabled when the edit button is clicked. Also, you *may* prefer to use the `IsReadOnly` property instead of `IsEnabled`.

UPDATE >>>

I'm assuming that either your second form is launched from your first form, or they are both launched from somewhere else... in this case, you can add the property to the parent form and bind to it from the child form(s) with the `RelativeSource` binding that I have shown in the example.
 You can bind

Comment: 10x, but I don't understand how this CanEdit to connect from form1 to form2... and connect to textbox...?

Comment: hm...many many thanks...but i just wrote this:
form2 myform2 = new form2();
myform2.tboxName.IsEnabled=true; and work :D